# Elementary doubt in a proof in Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology"?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology" and am trying to solve the following problem:

> [image]

The distance in problem 2 is: $d''(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i -y_i|$ and the theorem $2.3$ is:

> [image]

I am confused at how to prove the inequalities there, because the distance given in theorem $2.3$ could be anything, for example $d_1$ could be $k|x_1-y_1|$ with $k>0$ so it doesn't seems that the inequality would hold for all possible distance functions. For example: Consider the vectors $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,0)$. If $d(x,y)=\max \{1000|x_1-y_1|,1000|x_2-y_2| \}$, then:

$$\overbrace{d(x,y)}^{1000}\leq \overbrace{d'(x,y)}^{1} \leq \overbrace{\sqrt{2} d(x,y)}^{\sqrt{2}\cdot 1000} $$

Which is false. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try searching this site. I think these have been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you are missing anything here. It must be that while defining $d$ to be the distance function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by using Theorem 2.3, the author assumes that the underlying metric spaces $(X_i,d_i)$ in the definition of the product space are all equal to $(\mathbb{R},d_e)$ where $d_e$ is the usual Euclidian metric $d_e(x,y)=\lvert x-y \rvert$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $d$ is essentially the *supremum metric* $d(x,y)=\sup_i \lvert x_i-y_i \rvert$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If this assumption is not made, then many counterexamples can be constructed like the one you gave in your question.